# unable to send HTTP Post request in Jmeter using Javascript as selected language in BSF sampler

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am trying to invoke a HTTP post request using BSF Sampler and the selected Language is JavaScript. And i am using Jmter 2.13 as the tool to send my request.
Below is the snippet of the code which i am using.

```
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://localhost/oauth/token";
    var params = "client_id=api_client&client_secret=sade1!&response_type=token&grant_type=client_credentials";
    http.open("POST", url, true);


    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
```

But I recieved an response error message as :

```
"org.apache.bsf.BSFException: JavaScript Error: Internal Error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined."
```

Could anyone suggest me if any imports are missing or if anything wrong in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Why not using HTTP Request instead?

Comment: Have done with HTTP request. but the existing script would fail even after passing the HTTP request header content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" locally and commom HTTP Header content type as ""application/Json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is something implemented in **browser**, JavaScript engines like [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) or [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) don't have this class.

For performance reasons it [is recommended to use JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language, equivalent code would be something like:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def post = new HttpPost('https://localhost/oauth/token')

def params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>()
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair('client_id', 'api_client'))
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair('client_secret', 'sade1'))
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair('response_type','token'))
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair('grant_type','client_credentials'))
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params))

def response = client.execute(post)

if (response.getStatusLine().statusCode == 200) {
    log.info(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()))
}
else {
    log.info('Error: ' + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase())
}
```

---

Also be aware that you can achieve the same using normal [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you can control [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header using [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Comment: I tried using HTTP Header Manager and defined the content type but it did not work for me. i would try the above suggestion..!

Comment: Can i save the returned response to a variable and parse the token to a variable as string ?